# Should each object handle its own rendering, or should a seperate class handle all rendering?

Tags: java, oop, rendering, slick2d

The title isn't very clear, but I don't know how else to formulate it. So feel free to suggest a new title.

I'm currently making a game in Java, with the Slick2D library. First, I was handling all rendering in the `render()` function of the main class. But even with just a few objects I found this was getting very messy.

Short sample, though the original code had a bit more to render:

```
    g.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, gc.getScreenWidth(), 128);                             //draw top UI
    g.fillRect(0, 128, gc.getScreenWidth(), 512, sky, 8, 512);              //draw background
    g.fillRect(0, 720 - 128, gc.getScreenWidth(), 128, ground, 128, 128);   //draw ground
    g.drawImage(charSprite, charX, charY);                                  //draw character
    g.drawImage(weaponSprite, weaponX, weaponY);                            //draw weapon

    for (firedArrows arrow : Arrow) {
        g.drawImage(arrowSprite, arrow.getPosX(), arrow.getPosY)            //draw all arrows
    }
```

So, I've now switched to having each object render itself.
In the main `render()` function I will call the `render()` method of the `level`, which in his turn will render the level and call the `render()` function of objects in the level.

> Main.render() => level.render() => render level
>
> ```
>                          => character.render() => render character
>                                                => weapon.render() => render weapon
>                          => monsters.render()  => render monsters
> ```

And so on and so on.

Which of these two methods would be preferred, and why?
Or is there maybe a third method that's preferred?

Comment: In general, OOP would point to the second form, because each class should handle its responsabilities. But maybe your example is so simple that it is not really needed. One caveat, don't mix the model clases with the UI implementation, so you can change the UI easily without touching the model.

Comment: At the moment, it is simple. But I'm definitely going to expand the game. Maybe add particle generators, and whatnot.

UI will in the future also be handled in a GUI class.
Thank you for the response!

Comment: I'd say both. Each object should be responsible for painting it self, but it should only do so when instructed to do so from a central repaint engine, this prevents objects from painting themselves out of sequence or while the game data is been updated

Comment: I don't think it is possible for the objects to be painted out of sequence. All logic is executed within an `update()` function. And after `update()`, `render()` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "correct" OO design IMHO would be to to decouple the domain model objects from the renderers. The Bridge and / or Visitor patterns might apply here.